# How to use cookies for getting multiple value on laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

Actually, I am new on cookies `(haven't work on it)` what I am trying to do is Whenever clients visit my site and read an article get the id of that read article (without login). whenever clients came back on the same site form the same device which `he/she` has visited Then hide article which has been already read show only not read articles.

I have to try to create cookies like this

```
Cookie::queue(cookie('key', 'value', $minute = 10));
request()->cookie('key');
```

but whenever I update value it only get only the latest value. so Is it possible to do it by using cookies? or is there any alternative that which I can use for making this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.Instead of using the simple value you have to use an array of ids.

Example:-

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('seen_posts', json_encode([1,2]), $minutes));
```

Updating cookies

```
$seen_posts = json_decode($request->cookie('seen_posts'),true);

$seen_posts[] = 3;

Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('seen_posts', json_encode($seen_posts), $minutes));
```

Comment: Thanks for you response but its not working well while i try it errors like this

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie::__construct() must be of the type string or null, array given, called in D:\_coding\Freelance\efiling\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\CookieJar.php on line 69

Do i have done any mistakes?

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: While  insert first time it works well but while updating its not updating cookies 
//while updating can we filter duplicate id?